# Before redirect set validtion error to view page

Tags: ajax, validation, laravel-5

i am calling the form from ajax and after submitting the form, validation error message not showing, ajax call on load.
my ajax code

```
$.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"/application/workpermit",
            data:dataString,
            success:function(data){
              $('#tabs-12 .workpermit').html(data);
              //alert(data); return false;
            }
      });
```

Success return the workpermit view with form

The controller part, after submitting

```
if ($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect("application/".$employer_maid_id."/edit?tab=tab11")
                        ->withErrors($validator)
                        ->withInput();
        }
```

Please any one suggest me, how to show the validation message

Answer (score 0):

if you are not refreshing the page you need to add(append) the message with js/jQuery

if you are redirecting from the page you can you Laravel's built in feature "Flash". Basically it's a one time Session [laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/session#flash-data)